# Han Solo chin scar

Tags: star-wars, han-solo

Harrison Ford got a scar on his chin from a car accident he had in real life, but is there a Star Wars in-universe explanation about Han Solo getting it?

Comment: He was chasing away some lions with a whip. Or was that someone else?

Comment: Indiana Jones flashback at start of The Last Crusade

Comment: He cut himself shaving. A lot.

Comment: @Cadence while on the run, as a fugitive, from Tommy Lee Jones ;)

Comment: LEIA: That razor’s too sharp! HAN: It’s fine! LEIA: It’s a clear and present danger to your chin! HAN: You worry too much prin— owwww

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is explained in the book *[Han Solo and the Lost Legacy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Lost_Legacy)* by Brian Daley.  We see him getting cut across his chin during a fight.

> The chief took a moment to slash at the pilot. Han suddenly realized
> how impetuous he had been; as if another man entirely had occupied his
> body for a moment. **He didn’t quite avoid the stroke and the knifepoint
> cut across his chin.**
>
> [ later ]
>
> “Don’t fold until the hand’s over, ” he encouraged her quietly. She turned to him with a labored smile, brushing her dirty fingers against his stubble of beard, **tracing the raw scar across his chin.** “You know, this is an improvement, Solo. You’re not Slick now, not so smooth and careless.”

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the page reference (not much use since you've evidently got the three-book compendium), putting in the correct book name and adding in a quote.